# Javascript: comparing two values always not equal

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to do something but im struggling with a stupid bug, hope you can help me.

As you can see in my code I have on server some check box and I attached to it a JavaScript function. This function gets two values (current value and original value).
My problem is when this function triggers on the `if` it always get to the first clause and never reach the else clause and it doesn't make any sense.

When I used few alerts in my code this is what happens:

case 1: **alert #1**  original: `false` current: true **alert #2**  `true`

case 2: **alert #1**  original: `false` current: false **alert #2**  `true`

As you can see, no matter what I get true on the 2nd alert.

Hope I managed to explain my problem.

```
<asp:CheckBox id="chkIsCustomQuantity" originalvalue="false" runat="server" onclick="checkChange(this.checked, this.attributes['originalvalue'].value" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function checkChange(value, originalValue) {

        //i added this for debugging purpose
        alert('original: ' + originalValue + ' ' + 'current: ' + value);
        alert(value != originalValue);

        if (value != originalValue) {
             // always happens
        }
        else {
              // never happens
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Use console.log and/or your debugger to inspect variable values. Trust me, you will never want to go back to alert() after that.

Comment: Unless you're a 13-year-old girl, "u" is not a word. Please use proper English.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`originalValue` is always a string. `value` is a boolean. So, they're never equal, but when you print them out they appear identical (since they're both converted to the same string value at that point).

You can fix this in a variety of ways. One simple way is to convert both to strings first:

```
if (String(value) != String(originalValue))
```

Comment: hmm so what i should be doing to solve this? edit: ok im stupid i just used toString()..

Comment: @Popokoko: I've updated my answer (you're too fast for me!) :-)

Comment: If they're coming checked from the server, you shouldn't need a custom attribute. Just use the `.defaultChecked` property. That'll give you a boolean just like `.checked`. `onclick="checkChange(this.checked, this.defaultChecked)"`

Comment: +1 Or within the function: `if (this.checked == this.defaultChecked) {...}`.